# Windows Service Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services, setup-project

I’m trying to create a set-up project for a windows service.  I’ve followed [this](http://philippsen.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-service-using-vs2010/) tutorial and many others like it but, after installing my service, I still can’t see the service.  I’ve added the primary output of the service to the application directory and created a custom action to include this output on Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall.

It claims that it installs correctly.

Should this work?  Is there anything else that I can try to get this to install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you create an installer for your service? It is separate from a Setup Project.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx

You can create an Installer by right-clicking on your service's *Design* window and selecting **Add Installer**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding the installer was a first step as described by dhirschl's answer. I then needed to add custom actions to the setup project.

Right click the setup project/view/custom actions

then add the primary output to every folder there.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622598/2498426)